# Error: Complex DataBinding accepts as a data source either an IList or an IListSource

Tags: c#, winforms, data-binding, combobox

I am trying to make a reservation in a Hospital when a patient select a clinic it should list the names of doctors in selected clinic

I make the query in `TableAdapter` in my Project DataSet wizard 
and it works fine when I test it in `Dataset` or if I bound it from `ComboBox` wizard 
but when I am trying to change data of comboBox using `comboBox.DataSource` I got 
this Error :

> Complex DataBinding accepts as a data source either an IList or an
>   IListSource.

Here is my code:

```
private void Reservation_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'mRMSDataSet.Departments' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
    this.departmentsTableAdapter.FillByCLinics(this.mRMSDataSet.Departments);
}

private void clinicNameComboBox_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    clinicDoctorsComboBox.DataSource = this.clinicDoctorsTableAdapter.FillByClinicDoctors(this.mRMSDataSet.ClinicDoctors, Convert.ToInt32(clinicNameComboBox.SelectedValue.ToString()));
    clinicNameComboBox.DisplayMember = "empName";
    clinicNameComboBox.ValueMember = "empId";
}
```

Comment: You should first fill the `DataTable`, then assign it to `DataSource`. Currently you have assigned an integer to `DataSource`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is self explanatory and documented. When you assign a value to `DataSource` property of your combo box which the value does not implement the `IList` or `IListSource` interfaces, you will receive an `ArgumentException`:

> Complex DataBinding accepts as a data source either an IList or an
>   IListSource.

In above code you assigned result of `Fill` method (which is usually `int`) to `DataSource` of your `ComboBox`. Instead you should first `Fill` the `DataTable`, then assign `DataTable` to `DataSource` of the control this way:

```
this.someTableAdapter.Fill(this.someDataSet.SomeTable);
comboBox1.DataSource = this.someDataSet.SomeTable;
```

Comment: No need to smack the guy down for asking a question this is documented.  It may be self explanatory to you, but clearly, not to the person asking the question.  He may have read the documentation and did not understand it.

Comment: @MikeMalter You may not like the tone of the answer, but I don't see anything rude in the answer or anything to change to make it more useful. The answer is not blaming the OP, it's just trying to point out it's an expected behavior which is clearly explained in the error message. In addition the answer tries to add more explanation to shows why the exception has been thrown and and how to solve the problem.

Comment: @MikeMalter look at [this search result](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22error+is+self+explanatory%22) or [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22message+is+self+explanatory%22).